# Running consecutive runs of ggplot for the same data and getting different results

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a wrote a simple `get_random_data_for_box_plot()` function,

I have used ggplot twice and passed the same data,
however I get different points. how come?
generated images are attached.

```
export_image_to_file_now <- function(file_path, iter){
      file_name <-  paste0(file_path,iter, ".jpg")
      print(paste0("file_name: ", file_name))
      ggsave(file_name)
    }
    
    get_random_string <-function(num_words = 5, max_num_characters = 6 ){
      string_total <- ''
      
      for (i in seq(1,num_words)) {
        word_len <- runif(n = 1,min = 2,max = max_num_characters )
        string_total <- paste(string_total, stri_rand_strings(n = 1, length = word_len))
      }
      return (string_total)
    }
    
    get_random_data_for_box_plot <-function(){
      num_boxes <- round(runif(n = 1, min = 2 ,max = 9))
      names_boxes <- c()
      values_boxes <- c()
      mean_vec <- runif(n = num_boxes, min = -50 ,max = 150)
      sd_vec <- c()
      
      for (idx in seq(1,num_boxes)) {
        sd <- runif(n = 1, min = 0 ,max = abs(round(mean_vec[idx]/2)))  
        sd_vec <- c(sd_vec, sd)
      }
      
      for (idx in seq(1, num_boxes)) {
        box_name <- rep(get_random_string(num_words = 1))
        num_points_per_box <- round(runif(n = 1, min = 5 ,max = 7 ))
          
        names_boxes <- c(names_boxes, rep(box_name,num_points_per_box))
        value_per_box <- rnorm(n = num_points_per_box,
                               mean = mean_vec[idx],
                               sd = sd_vec[idx])
        values_boxes <- c(values_boxes,value_per_box)
      }
      
      data_boxplot <- data.frame(name = names_boxes, 
                                 value = values_boxes)
      return (data_boxplot)
    }
    
    
    data = get_random_data_for_box_plot()
    
    data %>%
      ggplot(aes(x=name, y=value, fill=name)) +
      geom_boxplot() +
      geom_jitter(color="black", size=0.4, alpha=0.9) +
      theme_ipsum() +
      ggtitle("just a title")
    
    export_image_to_file_now(paste0(getwd(),"/"), "example1")
    
    data %>%
      ggplot(aes(x=name, y=value, fill=name)) +
      geom_boxplot() +
      geom_jitter(color="black", size=0.4, alpha=0.9) +
      theme_ipsum() +
      ggtitle("just a title")
    
    export_image_to_file_now(paste0(getwd(),"/"), "example2")
```

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Comment: You call `geom_jitter` which does random sampling. Use `set.seed` for reproducibility.

Comment: Well you do have a function called `get_random_data_for_box_plot()`, and it uses `runif()` which gives a random result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed `geom_jitter` uses random sampling, therefore I had to use `set.seed`(thank you Roland)

Answer (score 0):

You are taking multiple random draws with `geom_jitter()` and `runif()`  and the random number generator will (almost certainly) will produce different random values every time you run the code. You can stop this by using `set.seed()` with an arbitrary seed number in the parentheses. This will produce the same values every time.